# Why the need to specify `dplyr::filter`?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I know that if there is a namespace conflict for a method name (e.g. `filter`), syntax such as `dplyr::filter` helps to specify which package's method you want to use. However, I'm seeing the usage of this syntax in official documents even in situations where there is no namespace conflict.

For example, here's a snippet from the official gt docs: https://gt.rstudio.com/

```
library(gt)

# Define the start and end dates for the data range
start_date <- "2010-06-07"
end_date <- "2010-06-14"

# Create a gt table based on preprocessed
# `sp500` table data
sp500 |>
  dplyr::filter(date >= start_date & date <= end_date) |>
  dplyr::select(-adj_close) |>
  gt() |>
  tab_header(
    title = "S&P 500",
    subtitle = glue::glue("{start_date} to {end_date}")
  ) |>
  fmt_currency() |>
  fmt_date(columns = date, date_style = "wd_m_day_year") |>
  fmt_number(columns = volume, suffixing = TRUE)
```

I'm curious. Why is there a need to specify `dplyr::filter` in this case instead of just using `filter`?

Comment: What do you mean? This no call of `library(dplyr)` here, so if you call `filter()` directly it will result into an error.

Comment: The use of the double colon `dplyr::filter` can be used for more than just namespace disambiguation, it's also used to utilize a function when its encouraging namespace has not been explicitly loaded into the search path. As @LiangZhang started, since that example from `gt`'s sample code does explicitly load `dplyr`, the only way to get that version of the function to be used is to use the double colon notation.

Comment: It is increasingly common (I find) to use `::` in cases where it may not be necessary, but when it may increase readability by future readers (including yourself). In this example, it probably isn't so relevant, but in cases where one may use a function from a package that is less well know, it can be helpful to prefix the package as a reminder to future readers of where that function comes from.

Comment: would someone like to post an answer for this question-  @LiangZhang maybe? It seems like there's all the constituent parts of a good answer

Comment: @joran This is also a problem when the function comes from a *well known* package, like `dplyr::filter`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for explaining @r2evans. If you can post an answer to this question, I'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things.
As the comments point out,  if you never called `library(dplyr)`, a call `filter()` will either fail or find some other function named "filter."

I strongly recommend you read the manual  "R-exts"  in detail.  When building a package, there's a difference between naming a "Depends" package vs. an "Imports" package.  By using the `package::function` format, you can access the function without having to load the library.  That's more or less the recommended approach when one package uses only one or two (of many) functions in the called package.

And, finally,  when  FutureYou revisits PresentYou's codebase, there's no ambiguity about which function/package was intended to be called.   As time goes by,  one's default set of loaded libraries changes (and/or their order of loading).  By using `package::function` you avoid mind-rending performance failures.